# Import-Module IISAdministration Fails With "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Administration..."

Tags: powershell, iis

I recently wrote some setup scripts to help new developers get set up with some of my company's .NET Framework web solutions. The scripts install required modules, enable required IIS features, and handle IIS / database setup.

The module installation:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
Install-Module -Name IISAdministration
```

The IIS feature setup:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole, IIS-WebServer, IIS-CommonHttpFeatures,
IIS-NetFxExtensibility45, IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics, IIS-HttpLogging, IIS-Performance, IIS-WebServerManagementTools,
IIS-ManagementScriptingTools, IIS-StaticContent, IIS-DefaultDocument, IIS-DirectoryBrowsing, IIS-ASPNET45,
IIS-ISAPIExtensions, IIS-ISAPIFilter, IIS-HttpCompressionStatic, IIS-ManagementConsole, IIS-WindowsAuthentication
```

On this developer's machine, we ran the scripts but they fail at the step `Import-Module "IISAdministration"` with this error:

```
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked on his machine, and he does have `IIS Management Console` and `IIS Management Scripts and Tools` enabled in IIS. We also ran `Install-Module -Name IISAdministration` in Windows Powershell in case it needed to be brought in from legacy PowerShell. We ran `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*Microsoft.Web.Administration*" }` on both our laptops and the results were almost identical, except that I had instances of the DLL in the following locations where he did not. I don't know that any of these locations are even things I can control:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.Web.Admin#\bfdf5ddb20c18de5bfcf47d0c7aaf2b3\Microsoft.Web.Administration.ni.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Web.Admin#\f932d02ad9ce7789bb5f6ddef72a4d5d\742912 Microsoft.Web.Administration.ni.dll
C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\InFlight\1b14b4e88b56d70153030000585bb875\amd64_microsoft.web.administration-nonmsil_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_7e61e0a530348d8b
C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\InFlight\1b14b4e88b56d70153030000585bb875\msil_microsoft.web.administration_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_10b0711179aace95
C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\InFlight\1b14b4e88b56d70153030000585bb875\x86_microsoft.web.administration-nonmsil_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_2243452177d71c55
```

There are loads of posts on StackOverflow about this problem from a few years ago saying that older versions of PowerShell 7 didn't come with support for IIS, but given it's all old info I'm not sure that it's still relevant. Troubleshooting steps we tried:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled PowerShell 7.2.1
- Tried to reinstall the IISAdministration module using AllowClobber

We were able to import the module in Windows PowerShell and run cmdlets from it, but we need to run this in PowerShell 7.2.1 because we need to run certificate commands that don't work right in Windows PowerShell. Clearly something is missing on his machine that I have inadvertently done correctly on mine. What else do we need to do to use IISAdministration with PowerShell 7.2.1?

Comment: Most Windows specific PowerShell modules might work only in 5.1 compatibility mode,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_windows_powershell_compatibility?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @LexLi I'm using PowerShell 7.2.1 on my machine and I can import the `IISAdministration` module with no fuss and as far as I know have not used that compat argument - is there a reason it would work with my machine but not his? We're both on Windows 10, same build.

Comment: The same question you can use as a reference: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c98c5803-a67d-4505-8e13-988251c52a05/iisadministration-does-not-work-on-powershell-7-even-the-latest-release-candidate?forum=iissetup](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c98c5803-a67d-4505-8e13-988251c52a05/iisadministration-does-not-work-on-powershell-7-even-the-latest-release-candidate?forum=iissetup) and [https://github.com/PowerShell/WindowsCompatibility/issues/84](https://github.com/PowerShell/WindowsCompatibility/issues/84).

Comment: @samwu I have found both of those posts. The first post is old and refers to 7, not 7.2.1, which targets .NET 6. The second post also refers to an old version, 7.0.3, and links to the first link you provided. Neither explain why it works on my machine but not on my teammate's machine so there has to be more going on here. If it didn't work, period, I should not be able to run these scripts without issue.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: I'll give that a shot; thank you!

Comment: The Microsoft support site has nothing for PowerShell that I can find. Where on that site would you suggest I open a case?

Comment: This link: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-business-1f4c4d09-9047-28ac-bb3b-618757e3bffd](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-business-1f4c4d09-9047-28ac-bb3b-618757e3bffd).

Comment: If I install the module using `Install-Module -Name IISAdministration -Scope AllUsers -AllowClobber` it installs to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` and from that directory the module seems to function. If there are any copies of the module living in the user's `C:\Users\USER\Documents\PowerShell\Modules` folder or in `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules`, the module fails to access the Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll module available in `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv`. I'm not clear on why, and I'm still testing it out on some dev machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found in my case that if you don't install IISAdministration to the AllUsers scope it can screw up the module's ability to read in types from Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll. To do this:

```
Install-Module -Name IISAdministration -Scope AllUsers -AllowClobber
```

If there are any copies of the module living in the user's `C:\Users\USER\Documents\PowerShell\Modules` folder or in `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules` they must be deleted or the module fails to access the `Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` module available in `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv`. I'm not clear on why, and I'm still testing it out on some dev machines. Would be open to any feedback from folks here as to why that might be. There is also a GitHub issue open [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17012).

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question. That's great! If that's the case, please mark it as such.

Comment: I marked it as answer, though I believe there's still an actual defect somewhere. That's tracked in the bug report though.

Answer (score -1):

This problem can also be caused by not having IIS feature installed on the machine.

`Add Feature > Web Server`

Comment: While that is one potential issue with using the cmdlet, it's not a factor in this reported issue.